# Xml parsing with python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am parsing `xml` with python using `xmltodict`. But i am getting following error ,

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 2890, column 2
```

Here is my code ,

```
import xmltodict
import urllib2
url="url here"
data=xmltodict.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
print data
```

I have also tried using `etree`

Here is the code ,

```
import urllib2
import lxml.etree as ET
print 'Started Execution here'
url="url here"
xmldata = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
root = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
print 'Done'
print root
```

It is also giving me error,

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: ClinicID line 54 and Type, line 55, column 14
```

I know there is problem in `xml` . 
My question is that is there is any way to read the `xml` with all the nodes except that caused error ?

Comment: "*is there is any way to read the xml with all the nodes except that caused error?*" No, not with XML tools. Your input is not well-formed. Therefore it is not XML (by definition).